# How to build object files only once with cmake?

Tags: cmake

I have a CMakeLists.txt file that looks like this:

```
add_executable(exec1 exec1.c source1.c source2.c source3.c)
add_executable(exec2 exec2.c source1.c source2.c source3.c)
add_executable(exec3 exec3.c source1.c source2.c source3.c)
```

The source1.o source2.o source3.o files take a really long time to build, and since they are common to all the executables, I want each of them to be built only once. The current behavior for cmake, however, is to rebuild them for each exec target separately, which is an unnecessary duplication of effort.

Is there a way to tell cmake to build object files only once?

Comment: I am just curious. How long does it take to make your Object files?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No. This would be difficult to achieve since the source files could be compiled with different compiler options, post-build steps, etc.

What you can do is to put the object files into a static library and link with that instead:

```
add_library(mylib STATIC source1.c source2.c)
add_executable(myexe source3.c)
target_link_libraries(myexe mylib)
```

EDIT: of course, you can put it in a **shared** library as well.

Comment: Take care with that approach. Shared libraries may be friendlier if there are lots of exes involved http://blog.flameeyes.eu/2008/01/21/what-to-do-with-shared-code

Comment: Yes, of course. I think I just assumed that the OP wanted the code duplicated in each of the executables.

Comment: If the static/object library compiles slowly (e.g. C++ sources with Boost or Eigen) and contains only a few source files, then this approach can increase build times for parallel builds, because `myexe` target will not begin building until `mylib` is built. In my real-world project the difference in total build time appeared to be 22 s vs 38 s (resp. duplicated compilation vs `OBJECT` library).

Answer (score 17):

Yes, in CMake 2.8.8 you can use an object library, which is a kind of virtual library that has the same organizational and dependency properties of a real static or shared library, but does not produce a file on disk. See CMake Tutorials: [Object Library](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/tutorials/Object-Library).

Answer (score 7):

In recent CMake versions, you can use an object library. It will mostly behave like any libraries but won't archive it into a static library:

```
add_library(my_cpps OBJECT a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp)
```

You can then "link" it to other targets:

```
add_library(my_lib1 d.cpp e.cpp f.cpp)
target_link_libraries(my_lib1 PUBLIC my_cpps)

add_library(my_lib2 f.cpp g.cpp h.cpp)
target_link_libraries(my_lib2 PUBLIC my_cpps)
```

Comment: If the static/object library compiles slowly (e.g. C++ sources with Boost or Eigen) and contains only a few source files, then this approach can increase build times for parallel builds, because `myexe` target will not begin building until `mylib` is built. In my real-world project the difference in total build time appeared to be 22 s vs 38 s (resp. duplicated compilation vs `OBJECT` library).

Comment: @Ruslan not necessarily. When using ninja, it can start building even though the object library is not done yet. I will defer linking until the object library is done.

Comment: Would you share some reference related to Object file in using Ninja?

Comment: Ninja will do the same thing as other build system but it will parallelize more than the typical build system. That's the only difference. I don't have references other than what I observed when using and what's on their website.