# Grouping the unit tests together in CMake

Tags: unit-testing, cmake

I have different test builds within CMake, with the last one running ALL the tests.
Does the last test `UTestAll` build each unit test separately and if so, does that mean the same test ends up getting built multiple times? Perhaps there's a way to group the unit tests such that it's only built once?

Or rather, is there a way to have the option to exclude a particular target from running? So say at some point I wouldn't want to run `UTestAll` when running on jenkins pipeline but would want to run locally.

*#Test1*

```
set(THIS UTest1)
string(TOUPPER DO_BUILD_${THIS} THIS_FLAG)

if (${THIS_FLAG})
  add_executable(
          ${THIS}
          src/Test1.cpp
  )

  target_include_directories(${THIS} PRIVATE include)
  target_link_libraries(${THIS} PUBLIC lib1
endif()
```

*#Test2*

```
set(THIS UTest2)
string(TOUPPER DO_BUILD_${THIS} THIS_FLAG)

if (${THIS_FLAG})
  add_executable(
          ${THIS}
          src/Test2.cpp
  )

  target_include_directories(${THIS} PRIVATE include)
  target_link_libraries(${THIS} PUBLIC lib2
endif()
```

*#Test3*

```
set(THIS UTest3)
string(TOUPPER DO_BUILD_${THIS} THIS_FLAG)

if (${THIS_FLAG})
  add_executable(
          ${THIS}
          src/Test3.cpp
  )

  target_include_directories(${THIS} PRIVATE include)
  target_link_libraries(${THIS} PUBLIC lib3
endif()
```

*# Run ALL Tests*

```
set(THIS UTestAll)
string(TOUPPER DO_BUILD_${THIS} THIS_FLAG)

if (${THIS_FLAG})
  add_executable(
          ${THIS}
          src/Test1.cpp
          src/Test2.cpp
          src/Test3.cpp
  )

  target_include_directories(${THIS} PRIVATE include)
  target_link_libraries(${THIS} PUBLIC lib1 lib2 lib3
endif()
```

Comment: For build(compile) a specific source file only once, create an OBJECT library: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388877/how-to-build-object-files-only-once-with-cmake.

Comment: So something like? https://products.groupdocs.app/viewer/view?file=d7bce9a4-dbac-4c60-bb4e-7fba0787b1eb/CMake.txt

Comment: Out of curiosity, it looks like you're not using the in-built testing features of CMake. Is that so? If so, why?

Comment: like what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can build each test as an object library, make an executable from each of that and then another one using all of them as follows:

```
# add object library for each file
add_library(UTest1_obj OBJECT)
target_sources(UTest1_obj PRIVATE src/Test1.cpp)
target_include_directories(UTest1_obj PRIVATE include)
[...]

# add executables linking one object each
add_executable(UTest1)
target_link_libraries(UTest1 PRIVATE UTest1_obj)
[...]

# add an executable with all objects
add_executable(UTestAll)
target_link_libraries(UTestAll PRIVATE UTest1_obj UTest2_obj UTest3_obj)
```

It may make sense to take a look at CMake macros, so it isn't that repetetive.
It may also make sense to look into `ctest` and some testing framework (GoogleTest, Catch2 or something like that)

Comment: Curious about how it optimizes the original CMake. Each target is run separately. Can you confirm if what I have runs unit test *multiple times* in `UTestAll`?